# How to read a particular value ("text") from the following JSON file using Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read the text values from the following JSON file.

https://www.ted.com//talks/marina_abramovic_an_art_made_of_trust_vulnerability_and_connection/transcript.json?language=en

I want to print whatever there is in "text" key.

I am trying this code but not getting the results :

```
import json
import urllib

url = "https://www.ted.com//talks/marina_abramovic_an_art_made_of_trust_vulnerability_and_connection/transcript.json?language=en"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

def iterate(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print(value)
            iterate(value)
            continue


iterate(data)
```

Comment: You should show the full code. How are you getting the data in the first place?

Comment: Hi i have added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this please ?

```
import urllib
import json
url = "https://www.ted.com//talks/marina_abramovic_an_art_made_of_trust_vulnerability_and_connection/transcript.json?language=en"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

def iterate(data):
    if "paragraphs" not in data: # check if paragraphs node exits
        return
    for cues in data['paragraphs']: #iterate through paragraphs node
        for d in cues['cues']: #iterate through cues
            print d['text']  


iterate(data)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works like charm